# Change JavaScript output before terser kicks in in Angular

Tags: angular, terser

Is it possible in an Angular 13 project to change the content in the generated *main.js* file before it is given to the minifier/optimizer/obfuscator (in Angular, it is terser)?

A very exotic requirement is forcing us to do a search/replace for a variable name. i18n is generating variable names based on the directory and we need a reproducible build.

Comment: Can you express your original need, rather than asking about what you think is the solution ?

Comment: Why do you need to perform the search and replace ***after*** the build?

Comment: We need a reproducible build, that is with same versions the build output must be exactly the same. Ng-Bootstrap uses i18n. The template compiler of angular will generate variable names based on where the template file is. You will find a variable name like this in main.js: MSG_C__PATHTOPROJECT_NODE_MODULES__NG_BOOTSTRAP_NG_BOOTSTRAP_FESM2015_NG_BOOTSTRAP_MJS__66. 
Unfortunately, the variable name contains the full path (in linux also) in its name.

Source code of angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/compiler/src/render3/view/template.ts#L228